# Char concatenation and memory reallocation

Tags: c, concatenation, radix

I am trying to concatenate single digits to a string:

```
include <stdio.h>
include <stdlib.h>
include <string.h>

int main() {

  char *test="";
  int i;

  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
    char *ic;
    ic = malloc(2);
    sprintf(ic, "%d", i);

    // printf("%d\n", strlen(test));

    if (strlen(test) == 0) 
      test = malloc(strlen(ic));
      strcpy(test, ic);
    } else {
      realloc(test, strlen(test) + strlen(ic));
      strcat(test, ic);
    }

  }
  printf("%s\n", test);
  // printf("%c\n", test);
  free(test);
  test = NULL;
  return 0;
}
```

My goal is for the result of the final `printf ("%s", test)` be `0123456789`.

Comment: `ic=malloc(2);` - why? Why not `char ic[2]`? Or why not simply use `'0' + <digit>` to get the character representation of a digit?

Comment: Probably because this is a learning exercise.

Comment: Exactly, thank you anyway for your time

Answer (score 1):

Remember that strings are terminated with null characters. When you allocate memory for a string, you must add an extra byte for the null. So you'll need to add 1 to each of your `malloc()` and `realloc()` calls. For example:

```
test = malloc(strlen(ic) + 1);
```

Remember, also, that `realloc()` is allowed to "move" a variable to a new location in memory. It may need to do that in order to find enough contiguous unallocated space. It can also return `NULL` if it's unable to allocate the memory you've requested, so you should call it like this:

```
char *new_mem = realloc(test, strlen(test) + strlen(ic) + 1);
if (new_mem == NULL) {
  // Not enough memory; exit with an error message.
} else {
  test = new_mem;
}
```

Comment: A big thank you for the quick and clear explanations. Thank you for your time I hope one day to learn myself.

Answer (score 0):

A few issues:

1. `char *test="";` - you point test to a constant C string. You don't write to it, but it's dangerous and will compile in C++. The type of `""` is `const char*`.
2. `strlen` returns the length of the string not the buffer size. You need to add +1 to include the NULL character. This is your biggest issue.
3. A short known fixed size small buffer like `ic` should be allocated on the stack. A simple char array. You also forgot to `free()` it.

Comment: Very well, thank you for your further explanation it is noted. I'm still confused with the type const char (wikipedia does not explain very well for my taste this). My question is, is it necessary to free the memory for all declared pointers ? the time that allocat es memory, it must be emptied after? Thank you very much ...

Comment: Memory management is at the core of C/C++. I strongly suggest that you find a book (many exist) and read the basics. It will save you a lot of time. `const char` means that the type is consant - read only access. The `""` can be used in multiple places in the code using a single copy of `""`. If it is changed in runtime, other places that use it will fail.